# ¿Cómo puedo crear un GIF animado con PHP?

Tags: php, gif

He estado buscando librerías para poder crear gif animados con php, pero no he tenido resultados favorables.
Si conocen alguna forma de crear gif animados desde el lado del servidor se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: en github hay varios https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=github+gif+animated+php

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar [gif-endec](https://github.com/stil/gif-endec)

Solo le deberas pasar las imagenes, ejemplo

```
<?php
use GIFEndec\Color;
use GIFEndec\Encoder;
use GIFEndec\Frame;
use GIFEndec\IO\FileStream;

$gif = new Encoder();

foreach (glob('skateboarder/frame*.gif') as $file) {
    $stream = new FileStream($file);
    $frame = new Frame();
    $frame->setDisposalMethod(1);
    $frame->setStream($stream);
    $frame->setDuration(30); // 0.30s
    $frame->setTransparentColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    $gif->addFrame($frame);
}

$gif->addFooter(); // Se requiere después de que haya terminado de agregar los frames

// Copia el archivo resultante de animacion
$gif->getStream()->copyContentsToFile('skateboarder/animation.gif');
```